# Link cannot be clicked or hover when i ran with resolution 1768x992 or below

Tags: html, css

so i think this is just about navigation i made and it work just fine, but i just realize when i change my resolution to 1768x992 that my navigation won't work like i want it

The problem is when i ran code with resolution 1768x992 or below i cannot click or hover the home link. The first-child (home) on the left side cannot be hover but when i shake my mouse a little bit to the right near registration it will show the hover action. And moreover i cannot click the home link.

first thought was my border stack eraser

`.nav:nth-child(n+2){
    margin-left:-2px;
}`

but when i clean it and see what happened it just feel the same. no clue what's going on with home button, can some body please explain it to me why...

o ya this is my code

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica
}
/*header*/

header {
  width: 100%;
}
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#logo img {
  width: 40%;
}
/*navigation*/

.navigation {
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-head {
  font-size: 0;
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav a {
  color: #e74c3c;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 2px #e74c3c;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  min-width: 20%;
}
.nav:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-left: -2px;
}
.nav:hover {
  padding: 16px 18px;
  margin-top: -16px;
}
.nav.currentPage {
  padding: 16px 18px;
  margin-top: -16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="index.php">
        <img src="Asset/Logo.png" alt="logo" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul class="nav-head">
        <li class="nav" id="nav1"><a href="index.php">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav" id="nav2"><a href="registrasi.php">REGISTRATION</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav" id="nav3"><a href="panduan.php">TUTORIAL</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav currentPage" id="nav4"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I tried it but I am not getting it. please tell me which button is not working ?

Comment: @sagarkodte the home button the home link inside of the ul and li tags

Comment: actually here home button is working and contact us button is unable to click.

Comment: @sagarkodte obviously contact us has no link yet... idk how to explain the condition.. otherwise my english not that good.. it's about the home link that i made and the hover won't work like it sud be.. or maybe can u put that code in ur IDE so and run it into the chrome and u will see the different if u open in 1768x992 resolution

anyway, thx for respond man.. respect u